# custom error message for Rails build-in validation helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have a model like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
   validates_presence_of :name, :login, :email 
end
```

In the view form, if I leave say email empty and submit the form the error message by Rails will be :

```
email can't be blank.
```

I am wondering, how can I customize this error message for Rails build-in validation helpers?

I mean I would like `:name`, `:login` field use the **default** error message, but only want `:email` raise the message like "`You have to provide email address`" . How to achieve this?

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**

Answer (score 0):

Custom error message (default is: "can‘t be blank").

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
   validates_presence_of :name, :login
   validates_presence_of :email, :message => 'your custom messages'
end
```

http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001871

Comment: No, it raise the error now "Email your customer messages", it still has the "Email" string

Comment: By default, the error message will be prefixed by the name of the field.